# Crystal Report is not run on my vb.net 2010 project , after share in another pc

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, crystal-reports, vb.net-2010

I make a  bill, invoice, etc by using crystal report in vb.net 2010 and SQL Server project but I face a problem. I run the project on my pc is properly run but I share this project to another pc so is not run, crystal report viewer still loading then show a error

[image: error image]

[image: still loading crystal report viewer]

I think this error is related to OLE DB connection because I changed OLE DB server name. I chose my server name on that another pc so it properly runs. I have to share my project anywhere and run properly without changing this server name

[image: OLE DB server name change screen]

how to run my project anywhere without changing SQL server name?

it's my code with SQL data load in crystal report.

```
 If comboType.SelectedIndex = 0 Then 'detail type crystal report
        Dim dt As New DataTable
        With dt
            .Columns.Add("series_no")
            .Columns.Add("bill_no")
            .Columns.Add("sale_date")
            .Columns.Add("gross_amount")
            .Columns.Add("dis_rs")
            .Columns.Add("Sale_Return_Amo")
            .Columns.Add("net_amount")
            .Columns.Add("less")
            .Columns.Add("cash_pay")
            .Columns.Add("card_pay")
            .Columns.Add("mo_pay")
            .Columns.Add("balance")

        End With

        For Each dgr As DataGridViewRow In Me.DataGried_Sales_Report.Rows
            dt.Rows.Add(dgr.Cells(0).Value, dgr.Cells(1).Value, dgr.Cells(2).Value, dgr.Cells(3).Value, dgr.Cells(4).Value, dgr.Cells(5).Value, dgr.Cells(6).Value, dgr.Cells(7).Value, dgr.Cells(8).Value, dgr.Cells(9).Value, dgr.Cells(10).Value, dgr.Cells(11).Value)

        Next
        Dim f As New Show_Reports
        Dim rdoc As CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument
        rdoc = New CrystalReport_Detail_Sale
        rdoc.SetDataSource(dt)
        rdoc.SetParameterValue("FromD", txtPR_DateTimePicker1.Text)
        rdoc.SetParameterValue("ToD", txtPR_DateTimePicker2.Text)
        f.CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rdoc
        f.ShowDialog()
        f.Dispose()
```

Comment: So many questions... Are you able to give use any detail of the actual db, the environment, distribution method?  Is this a local db that is part of the app, a shared db?  How are you initializing the DB connection string?  Is the deployment something you will manage or are you expecting end users to install?  Why are your using OleDB and not SqlClient?

Comment: actually, I am already used SQL client for connection but the problem is when I operate this project to another vb.net application then occurs an error and my crystal report could not run properly. it shows the connection fails with the SQL server because I have taken a different SQL server address. I want to make an application flexible which can be run on any other computer of their own SQL server. I don't want to change the SQL server name again and again on the crystal report. so tell me the best solution related to my project.